# Can the transition from the selection UITextField press to another UITextField cause the UIView to reload in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have the following view as soon as my app loads:

[image: Figure 1: First view load]

As soon as I click on the Full name text field, the keyboard shows and shifts the elements a little bit to allow the register button stays appearing.

[image: Figure 2: App view after I click on the first UITextfield]

The problem appears when I move to the second text field. It causes the view to reload entirely and place all the elements in the view to their original place which makes the key board to hide the lowest elements. which is shown in the next figure

[image: Figure 3 showing the problem]

I have searched and checked if the problem comes from the fact that the keyboard loads `keyboardwillshow()` and `keyboardwillhide` do not get called at all when this problem happens as I have verified.

Can the transition from the selection UITextField press to another UITextField cause the UIView to reload Xcode? Please not that the UIText fields are in a

```
import UIKit
import SendBirdSDK

class LoginController: UIViewController {

    var keyboardShowing = false

    let inputsContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return view
    }()

    lazy var loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 88, g: 101, b: 161)
        button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    func handleLoginRegister() {
        if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            handleLogin()
        } else {
            handleRegister()
        }
    }


    func handleLogin(){

        guard let userid = fullNameTextField.text, (passwordTextField.text != nil) else {
            print ("Form is not valid")
            return
        }



        SBDMain.connect(withUserId: userid, completionHandler: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print (error)
                return
            }

            //successfully loggedin user

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


        })
    }



    let nameTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Full Name"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()

    let nameSeperatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view

    }()

    let fullNameTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Username"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()

    let fullNameSeperatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view

    }()

    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Password"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()

    lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "gameofthrones_splash")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return imageView
    }()



    lazy var loginRegisterSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
        return sc
    }()

    func handleLoginRegisterChange() {
        if keyboardShowing == true {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
        /*else  {
            view.endEditing(false)
        }*/

        let title = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        loginRegisterButton.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState())

        // change height of inputContainerView, but how???
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.constant = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 100 : 150

        // change height of nameTextField
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 0 : 1/3)
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
        nameTextField.isHidden = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0

        fullNameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        fullNameTextFieldHeightAnchor = fullNameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 1/2 : 1/3)
        fullNameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 1/2 : 1/3)
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 61, g: 91, b: 151)

        view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)
        view.addSubview(loginRegisterButton)
        view.addSubview(profileImageView)
        view.addSubview(loginRegisterSegmentedControl)


        setupInputsContainerView()
        setupLoginRegisterButton()
        setupProfileImageView()
        setupLoginRegisterSegmentedControl()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

        //connecting to the application
        SBDMain.initWithApplicationId("1662A8E8-F45F-454B-9E5E-02362342ECC5")



    }

   func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        print ("keyboardwillshow was called")

        if self.keyboardShowing {
            return
        }



            if self.keyboardShowing == false {
                self.inputsContainerView.frame.origin.y -= 58
                self.loginRegisterButton.frame.origin.y -= 58
                self.loginRegisterSegmentedControl.frame.origin.y -= 58
                self.profileImageView.frame.origin.y -= 58

            }
            self.keyboardShowing = true

    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

         print ("keyboardwillhide was called")

        if !self.keyboardShowing {
            return
        }


            if self.keyboardShowing == true {
                self.inputsContainerView.frame.origin.y += 58
                self.loginRegisterButton.frame.origin.y += 58
                self.loginRegisterSegmentedControl.frame.origin.y += 58
                self.profileImageView.frame.origin.y += 58
            }
            self.keyboardShowing = false

    }

    func setupLoginRegisterSegmentedControl() {
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        loginRegisterSegmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36).isActive = true
    }

    func setupProfileImageView(){

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true


    }

    var inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var nameTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var fullNameTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    func setupInputsContainerView(){
        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        print(self.inputsContainerView.frame.origin.y)
        inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor = inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        inputsContainerViewHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        inputsContainerView.addSubview(nameTextField)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(nameSeperatorView)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(fullNameTextField)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(fullNameSeperatorView)
        inputsContainerView.addSubview(passwordTextField)

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        nameTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        nameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true

        nameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        nameSeperatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeperatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeperatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        nameSeperatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        fullNameTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        fullNameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        fullNameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        fullNameTextFieldHeightAnchor = fullNameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)

        fullNameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        fullNameSeperatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        fullNameSeperatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullNameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        fullNameSeperatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        fullNameSeperatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        passwordTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullNameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        passwordTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor = passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
        passwordTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
    }

    func setupLoginRegisterButton(){

        //need x, y, width, height constraints
        loginRegisterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }



}

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat ) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

Comment: "reload Xcode" doesn't make sense.  Xcode is a Mac application, not part of your app.

Comment: Corrected it! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of moving the elements of the `UIView` move the whole view frame like this:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    print ("keyboardwillshow was called")

    if self.keyboardShowing {
        return
    }



        if self.keyboardShowing == false {
            /*self.inputsContainerView.frame.origin.y -= 58
            self.loginRegisterButton.frame.origin.y -= 58
            self.loginRegisterSegmentedControl.frame.origin.y -= 58
            self.profileImageView.frame.origin.y -= 58*/

            self.view.frame.origin.y -= 58

        }
        self.keyboardShowing = true

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

     print ("keyboardwillhide was called")

    if !self.keyboardShowing {
        return
    }


        if self.keyboardShowing == true {
           /* self.inputsContainerView.frame.origin.y += 58
            self.loginRegisterButton.frame.origin.y += 58
            self.loginRegisterSegmentedControl.frame.origin.y += 58
            self.profileImageView.frame.origin.y += 58*/

            self.view.frame.origin.y += 58
        }
        self.keyboardShowing = false

}
```